# Java: How to check if a java app has been run before on mac

Tags: java

I'm trying to program a Java app, but in order for it to work I need to have it check to see if it is the first time opening the app or not. Is there any way to do this on Mac so that if it is the first time opening the app then it will perform a certain action?

Comment: Does it use any database or file? May be we can put some kind of config value in db or some info in file to store last execution time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use java.util.prefs.Preferences as described [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPreferences/article.html). Also I tried google, that was the first thing that popped. Let's use Google first.

EDIT:

Here is an annotated file to show the steps.

1. Define a key, you could use a String each time, better not to for execution purposes as well as refactoring. This key will be used to access the preference later.
2. Create an instance of the Preferences class.
3. Define a node, again a good pick I like is using the class simple name instead of a String. This node will be where the preferences will be saved so that there are no clashes if you have different preferences with similar keys in different nodes.
4. Use get[Type]([KEY], [default_value]) to access it and set[Type]([KEY], [value]) to set it as follows.

You can run this app twice to see the difference.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;
public class Main {

// This key will be used to access the preference, could literally have any name and value
private static final String SOME_KEY = "some_key";

private Preferences preferences;

public Main(){
    // Defining a new node for saving preference. Analogoues to a location.
    preferences = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
}

public boolean firstRun(){
    // See what is save in under SOME_KEY, if nothing found return true, if something found, return that.
    return preferences.getBoolean(SOME_KEY, true);
}

public void run(){
    // Put the value of false in the preference with the key SOME_KEY
    preferences.putBoolean(SOME_KEY, false);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    System.out.println("Is this the frist time running this app?");
    System.out.println(main.firstRun());
    main.run();

}
}
```

Comment: I could do that. Walking my dog. Will do it as soon as get back.